# How to fix error : 'Web api showing blank page while fetching data from SQL Server after publishing it on iis'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

When I run my asp.net core application directly from Visual Studio, it runs easily and displays data of SQL Server, but when I published it to IIS, it does not display the data.

The API is published successfully and fetching string array but not backend dbms data.

Please help

No response with blank page

Comment: please check console log

Comment: public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

    }

Comment: please suggest me the right answer

Comment: What http code does your API return? Is it 200? Is your appsettings.json file reflecting the connection string correctly?

Comment: You might want to try a tool like Postman to run the API on the server. It gives you a convenient way of seeing what is going on including the response code and HTTP response being return. You can also just use the developer tools in Chrome by clicking (in Chrome) f12, Network and then clicking Preserve Log. At that point, you can go the the API endpoint and see what's coming back. You might find Postman a bit easier to read but the two techniques are equivalent.